# Magento 2 Blank Checkout Page after installing payment plugin

Tags: magento2, checkout, plugin

After installing a payments plugin (Poli Payments) in Magento 2, the checkout page is now blank.

I disabled this plugin and found that the checkout page is working again.

I have now enabled the plugin with the checkout page appearing blank.

My site required this plugin.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please contact with the Payment getway provider

Comment: Can you see errors in console?

Comment: I have tried to contact the payment plugin provided and were no help. I do not see any errors in my console.

Comment: which payment extension you have installed ?